# How to convert a single page to a dataframe with pypdf?

Tags: python, pandas, pypdf

I need to convert page 24 of the pdf downloaded from here https://www.wipo.int/edocs/pubdocs/en/wipo_pub_gii_2021.pdf
into a dataframe. I used the following code to read the pdf and having trouble converting it into a dataframe. What would be the way to do it?

```py
import pypdf
import tabula
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

reader = pypdf.PdfReader(r"C:\Users\smx\python\wipo_pub_gii_2021.pdf")
page = reader.pages[23]
print(page.extract_text())
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was not able to pip install pdftotext using company's laptop due to some restrictions. So unfortunately that is not an option for me.

Comment: I tried tabula.read_pdf approach but it returned an empty dataframe